# Devise sign_in 401 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just added an Admin model to my app.  When I create a new Admin, a session is created and works fine.  But after destroying the session by signing out, the sign_in page gives a "Invalid email or password." for a correct email and password.

This appears in the log.

```
Started POST "/admins/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-26 03:58:31 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dvbWVdXO+ZBTg8T5xy7ptCm7o0ipmasHWyCmepnpt6M=", "admin"=>{"email"=>"me@mjohnst.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

The record does exist:

```
2.0.0p0 :006 > Admin.all
  Admin Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "admins".* FROM "admins"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Admin id: 1, email: "me@mjohnst.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$EndylY4sv0hESXEnkSF6rONTWXegjkQyOLrhvlri3Glc...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 1, current_sign_in_at: "2013-04-26 05:55:34", last_sign_in_at: "2013-04-26 05:55:34", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-04-26 05:55:34", updated_at: "2013-04-26 06:10:04">]>
```

**EDIT 2:**

After a few days break from working on this app, the issue seemed to resolve itself... perhaps I just needed to restart my local dev server or something else small.

Comment: Do the drill once again. Check if the user is destroyed from the database by `User.find_by_email('youremail@something.com')` upon signing out. That can narrow down the problem scenario. :)

Comment: Checked with `Admin.all` and the record does exist.

Comment: this is really strange for me. I guess you haven't removed the database_authenticatable from your model. Can you provide an example app with this error?